# Google reCaptcha server side validation batch requests

Tags: rest, validation, batch-file, google-api, recaptcha

I am running a server that performs server-side validation for Google reCaptcha requests, using the api call `https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify?secret=...&response=...&remoteip-...`

Due to the nature of my service, I frequently must perform a large number of these validations in a short period of time. Is there a batch request feature for reCaptcha? If so, what is the request format?